# Ferramenta Design de telas com HTML5

Tags: html5, css3, framework

Saudações, busco ferramenta estilo drag-drop,intuitiva e facil. Capaz de inserir os componentes para um webapp referênte a parte visual.

Que gere automaticamente, ou em tempo real, o **codigo HTML5 e outros se requerido** e seja preferencia um serviço online, opcional instalavel seja win ou linux.
No aguardo

Comment: Sua pergunta está fora do escopo do site, recomendo a leitura de [o que devo evitar de perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) e a [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para saber como o site funciona, ele é diferente de um fórum.

Comment: o Axure é uma ferramenta muito boa (http://www.axure.com/) para criar protótipos de alta fidelidade para as telas. Ele gera o html dos protótipos, mas provavelmente você terá que editar uma coisa ou outra no html/css antes de mandar para produção.

Comment: Recomendo [Balsamiq](https://balsamiq.com/products/mockups/) para mockups. Infelizmente nenhuma ferramenta desse tipo vai gerar um código fonte de qualidade.